# Change default vuetify-loader variables scss file path

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-loader

I created a project using Vue CLI (with typescript support), and added Vuetify with `vue add vuetify`

This create a file tree like this:

```
project
 - public
 - node_modules
 - src
   - components
   - scss
     variables.scss
   - assets
   main.ts
```

But, I want to change this structure to use something like Clean Architecture. So, I have

```
project
 - public
 - node_modules
 - src
   - application
   - domain
   - infrastructure
   - web
     - components
     - assets
     - scss
       variables.scss
     main.ts
```

But if I do this, `vuetify-loader` no longer loads my `variables.scss` file. Based on the documentation, it looks like it only loads the path `src/scss/variables.scss`

Is there a way to change the default path to `src/web/scss/variables.scss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vue-cli-plugin-vuetify** appears to be hard-coded to expect that structure:

```
for (const ext of ['sass', 'scss']) {
    const path = `${folder}/${file}.${ext}`

    // If file doesn't exist in user
    // project, continue to next
    if (!fileExists(api, `src/${path}`)) continue

    // If file exists, push it into
    // the import statement
    data.push(`@import '@/${path}${end}`)
  }
```

[Source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/blob/master/packages/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify/util/helpers.js#L13)

There is already an [open issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/issues/187) in the repo to track for any change.